# Angular template with ng-repeat, could not able to track the value within it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I do have a angular template which populates the list of value in the search button.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
    ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
    role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
  <li role='option' aria-hidden='true' style='display: none'></li>    
  <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index"
      ng-class="{active: isActive($index)}" 
      ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" 
      ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" 
      role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
    <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match"
         query="query" template-url="templateUrl">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when i print the match from above repeat i get below JSON object, pasted just first index of the json array:

```
{"id":"typeahead-97-1116-option-0",
 "label":"Card/Key Request Informational Guide",
 "model":{
     "short_description":"Card/Key Request Informational Guide",
     "linkToPage":"dea5792147132100ba13a5554ee4902d",
     "published":"06-10-2019",
     "label":"Card/Key Request Informational Guide",
     "type":"kb","query_location":0,"publishedUTC":"06-10-2019",
     "url":"?id=kb_article&sys_id=29ae0b3edbb9fb407ebed77648961951",
     "sys_id":"29ae0b3edbb9fb407ebed77648961951",
     "number":"KB0010366","score":335.9009,"glyph":"file-text-o",
  }
}
```

based on the type i want to give the list a title. for example set of kb type under "Knowledge article" and type "sc" with title Service Catalog. The list i get is already ordered by bases on type.

Please let me know how to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator to determine the value of match.model.type and then set the title depending on that value.

```
<li>
    {{match.model.type === 'kb' ? 'Knowledge article' : match.model.type === 'sc' ? 'Service Catalog' : ''}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash for lookup:

```
$scope.typeLookup = {
    'kb': 'Knowledge article',
    'sc': 'Service Catalog',
    // ...
});
```

Use that hash in the template:

```
<li>
    {{typeLookup[match.model.type]}}
</li>
```